# Strange error message from MSBuild:

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm trying to compile a solution in Visual Studio and I get the same error whether I'm doing it from the command line (MSBuild) or from within VS. Here's the error message:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.tar
gets(2295,5): error : Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of 
the path 'C:\Workspace\VS2013\WebApps\Main\Src\CoreWebApps\Areas\Admin\Views\Web.config;
Areas\Admin\Views\Web.config'. 
[C:\Workspace\VS2013\WebApps\Main\Src\CoreWebApps\CoreWebApps.csproj]
```

So my question is why would it be looking for a file/path that has a semicolon in it? **...Areas\Admin\Views\Web.config;
Areas\Admin\Views\Web.config'**

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The .csproj file had multiple references to this web.config file, so when I brought it down to one this went away.